# Why should Hashicorp Packer file provisioner use temp directory?

Tags: file, provisioning, temporary-files, packer

I wonder what are the benefits of indirect **file upload within `/tmp` directory** [Packer `file` provisioner doc](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/file.html) suggests?

It's reasonable to assume uploading file/directory to the destination place without any intermediates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably recommended because the `/tmp` directory on any machine will likely fit the requirements mentioned in the docs for [the `destination` parameter:](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/file.html#destination)

> This value must be a writable location and any parent directories must already exist.

The `/tmp` directory usually exists and is usually readable and writeable by any process on your machine, so it's a good suggestion as a standard destination folder.

Comment: Thank you, Adil ‍♂️ Anyway moving a file from `/tmp` to the target destination requires to enable write permissions there too.